# How can i check for duplicates before using insert from select

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the following code to get data from linked server but how can i check whether there is a duplicate record or not in `sqlserver` table if there is skip for Next otherwise insert from select. i want to compare using the following filed 
`[CUSTOMER],[SO DATE],[SO NUMBER],[itemid],[PROMISED DATE],[PO #]`

```
insert db1.dbo.WORKORDERS 
   ([WORK ORDER #],[QUANTITY],[CUSTOMER],[SO DATE],[SO NUMBER],[ROUTING],[itemid],[CUSTOMER PN],[SHIP VIA],[PROMISED DATE],[COMMENTS],[PO #],[WO Notes])
select 
  convert(varchar(10), next value for dbo.WorkOrderSequence ),
x.Quantity,--
  x.Customer_Bill_Name,
  x.TransactionDate,
  x.Reference,
  X.Category,
  x.ItemID,
  x.PartNumber,
  x.WhichShipVia,
  x.ShipByDate,
  x.Comment2,
  x.CustomerInvoiceNo,
  x.SalesDescription
from
  openquery
  ([DB29],
    'select              
        Customers.Customer_Bill_Name,
        JrnlHdr.TransactionDate,
       Cast(JrnlRow.Quantity as Decimal(38,0)) as Quantity,
        JrnlHdr.Reference, 
        LineItem.Category,
       LineItem.ItemID ,
        LineItem.PartNumber, 
        Customers.WhichShipVia, 
        JrnlHdr.ShipByDate, 
        JrnlHdr.Comment2,
        JrnlHdr.CustomerInvoiceNo, 
        LineItem.SalesDescription    
FROM   Customers
    INNER JOIN JrnlHdr
ON Customers.CustomerRecordNumber = JrnlHdr.CustVendId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Address
ON Customers.CustomerRecordNumber = Address.CustomerRecordNumber
    INNER JOIN JrnlRow
ON JrnlHdr.PostOrder = JrnlRow.PostOrder
    INNER JOIN LineItem 
ON JrnlRow.ItemRecordNumber = LineItem.ItemRecordNumber
WHERE  JrnlHdr.JrnlKey_Journal = 11 AND JrnlHdr.TransactionDate = CURDATE()
AND JrnlHdr.PostOrder = JrnlRow.PostOrder  
AND JrnlHdr.CustVendId = Customers.CustomerRecordNumber 
AND JrnlRow.ItemRecordNumber = LineItem.ItemRecordNumber 
AND JrnlHdr.POSOisClosed = 0

)  as x
```

Comment: i only said "Distinct" may not be require if use where not clause properly,because distinct is evil.In your case may be your getting duplicate data that cannot be fix.First you should define what is duplicate records in your case i.e. combination of what all columns.Then use same column in where condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are to  use insert only so **Not exists** is the ideal choice and not much change is require.

try to fix error of your own,

```
insert db1.dbo.WORKORDERS 
   ([WORK ORDER #],[QUANTITY],[CUSTOMER],[SO DATE],[SO NUMBER],[ROUTING],[itemid],[CUSTOMER PN],[SHIP VIA],[PROMISED DATE],[COMMENTS],[PO #],[WO Notes])
Select 
  convert(varchar(10), next value for dbo.WorkOrderSequence ),
  Quantity,
  Customer_Bill_Name,
  TransactionDate,
  Reference,
  Category,
  ItemID,
  PartNumber,
  WhichShipVia,
  ShipByDate,
  Comment2,
  CustomerInvoiceNo,
  SalesDescription 
FROM
(
select 
x.Quantity,--
  x.Customer_Bill_Name,
  x.TransactionDate,
  x.Reference,
  X.Category,
  x.ItemID,
  x.PartNumber,
  x.WhichShipVia,
  x.ShipByDate,
  x.Comment2,
  x.CustomerInvoiceNo,
  x.SalesDescription
from
  openquery
  ([DB29],
    'select              
        Customers.Customer_Bill_Name,
        JrnlHdr.TransactionDate,
       Cast(JrnlRow.Quantity as Decimal(38,0)) as Quantity,
        JrnlHdr.Reference, 
        LineItem.Category,
       LineItem.ItemID ,
        LineItem.PartNumber, 
        Customers.WhichShipVia, 
        JrnlHdr.ShipByDate, 
        JrnlHdr.Comment2,
        JrnlHdr.CustomerInvoiceNo, 
        LineItem.SalesDescription    
FROM   Customers
    INNER JOIN JrnlHdr
ON Customers.CustomerRecordNumber = JrnlHdr.CustVendId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Address
ON Customers.CustomerRecordNumber = Address.CustomerRecordNumber
    INNER JOIN JrnlRow
ON JrnlHdr.PostOrder = JrnlRow.PostOrder
    INNER JOIN LineItem 
ON JrnlRow.ItemRecordNumber = LineItem.ItemRecordNumber
WHERE  JrnlHdr.JrnlKey_Journal = 11 AND JrnlHdr.TransactionDate = CURDATE()
AND JrnlHdr.PostOrder = JrnlRow.PostOrder  
AND JrnlHdr.CustVendId = Customers.CustomerRecordNumber 
AND JrnlRow.ItemRecordNumber = LineItem.ItemRecordNumber 
AND JrnlHdr.POSOisClosed = 0

)  as x'
)t4
where not exists(
select 1 from db1.dbo.WORKORDERS WO where wo.[CUSTOMER]=t4.Customer_Bill_Name
and [SO DATE]=t4.TransactionDate AND[SO NUMBER]=t4.Reference 
AND[itemid]=t4.ItemID and [PROMISED DATE]=t4.ShipByDate and [PO #]=t4.[PO #]
)
```

Comment: I GOT THIS ERROR `Msg 11719, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
NEXT VALUE FOR function is not allowed in check constraints, default objects, computed columns, views, user-defined functions, user-defined aggregates, user-defined table types, sub-queries, common table expressions, derived tables or return statements.` ANY IDEA

Comment: `[WORK ORDER #]` is created using  sequence function, is this error because of that? how can i fix it? thank you!

Comment: yes that sequence is not require in inner select in any case.even if problem is not solved.check my query now

Comment: added one record 6 times

Comment: no this is not possible.comment the insert tablename and only verify select resul set.problem is only in join column name inside where not exists.how can i debug ?

Comment: i added distinct on the second select and work well iam trying to run the same script to check whether it catches the dupe

Comment: Not 100% sure,but Distinct is not require.There is problem only in join columns inside where not exists.you should little more before using distinct.

Comment: it is working fine for me i will check it it in the morning again, i will mark it as an answer. why does `dsitinct` is not important i am using pervasive sql linked server

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142875/discussion-between-kumarharsh-and-joe).

Answer (score 2):

Use a correlated subquery with `exists` to eliminate rows that are already present:

`select ... from ... where not exists ( select 42 from db1.dbo.WorkOrders where ... )`

Answer (score 1):

You might find that the [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql) statement works for this purpose.  It lets you specify the destination table, source query, join criteria, and actions to take on match or no match.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [EXCEPT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql):

This will give you the records that do not exist on the linked server:

```
SELECT [CUSTOMER],[SO DATE],[SO NUMBER],[itemid],[PROMISED DATE],[PO #]
FROM current_database
EXCEPT
SELECT [CUSTOMER],[SO DATE],[SO NUMBER],[itemid],[PROMISED DATE],[PO #]
FROM linked_server_current_database
```

This will give you the records that do not exits on the current server:

```
SELECT [CUSTOMER],[SO DATE],[SO NUMBER],[itemid],[PROMISED DATE],[PO #]
FROM  linked_server_current_database
EXCEPT
SELECT [CUSTOMER],[SO DATE],[SO NUMBER],[itemid],[PROMISED DATE],[PO #]
FROM current_database
```